# Generating an AssemblyInfo file in an MVC6 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, assemblyinfo

I have created a brand new MVC6 project from a template in visualstudio community edition.

As opposed to previous versions of MVC I can't see an assemblyinfo file in the properties folder.  I'd like to get one set up with my auto incrementing version numbers on build.

If I compare the code of previous assemblyinfo files, there appear to be fields with GUIDS and things. I'm not sure what is mandatory and what is nice to have.

Is there a wizard for creating an AI file? Can I just manually create an AI class and put in only the version tag?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, it appears to be the case that https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file the project.json file appears to have replaced AssemblyInfo (along with a number of other things).

If you're looking for auto-version number in an MVC6 project you edit the version number in project.json.